# Problem linking to Catch2 library installed with Conan 2.0 in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, catch2

I recreated my issue on smaller project. Let's assume there are these files (also build directory):

```
├── add.hpp
├── add-test.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── conanfile.txt
```

add.hpp:

```
inline int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

add-test.cpp:

```
#include <catch2/catch_all.hpp>
#include "add.hpp"

TEST_CASE("testing add") {
    REQUIRE(add(1, 1) == 2);
}
```

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
catch2/3.3.1

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

I use the following CMake script to build all of this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(add LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "build/conan_toolchain.cmake")
# Required to be set.
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
# CMake can't find Conan packages without these two lines
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Catch2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(add-test add-test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(add-test Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
```

Conan profile is:

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=12.2
os=Linux
```

I use the following commands to build my project (Assuming build/ is empty):

```
conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

CMake configuration and Conan install go fine, then when building I get a swarm of linker errors, all are connected with Catch2. Some of them are like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/add-test.dir/add-test.cpp.o: in function `Catch::BinaryExpr<int, int>::~BinaryExpr()':
/home/fungor/.conan2/p/catchff10ed8b5da5a/p/include/catch2/internal/catch_decomposer.hpp:73: undefined reference to `Catch::ITransientExpression::~ITransientExpression()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/add-test.dir/add-test.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5Catch10BinaryExprIiiEE[_ZTIN5Catch10BinaryExprIiiEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Catch::ITransientExpression'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/add-test.dir/add-test.cpp.o: in function `Catch::BinaryExpr<int, int>::streamReconstructedExpression(std::ostream&) const':
/home/fungor/.conan2/p/catchff10ed8b5da5a/p/include/catch2/internal/catch_decomposer.hpp:80: undefined reference to `Catch::formatReconstructedExpression(std::ostream&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Catch::StringRef, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
... (a bunch more of these undefined references)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried:

- clearing Conan cache, rebuilding packages
- different Conan profiles: different CPP standards, build configs.

I just need Catch2 to work with my project.

[this seems similar to mine, but in my case libstdc++ is already set to ...++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019721/why-cant-i-link-to-spdlog-library-installed-with-conan)

EDIT 1: Stripped question to be more minimal.

EDIT 2: Recreated my problem on smaller scale.

EDIT 3: Included information about conanfile.txt and corrected CMake script.

Comment: what's in `main.cpp`? Have you used the correct macros? https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/v2.x/docs/own-main.md#top

Comment: is this the most minimal example you could devise to reproduce this problem? ([mre]) (I think not- like- first of all, you've got a bunch of other libraries in here that probably aren't necessary to reproduce the problem)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am not using my own main() for Catch2. My main.cpp is built in executable, which is the end target for my project (other lib_x are just supporting it). 
Tests are just like this:
`TEST_CASE("Testing class X") { // code }`

Comment: @user I agree that information about rang and zlib is in some way excessive. The reason why I provided it is to show that apart from Catch2 the rest of my dependencies are working.

Comment: You'll either need to either provide your own main or use the catch macros to define one for you

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am sorry, I do not understand what do you mean. I followed starting guide from Catch2 repository, I made my tests the way I described above and they even worked, when I used FetchContent instead of Conan 2.0. Each library has number of .cpp files that are used to built targets like "lib-x-test" which are executables. Clearly, my problem is related to how I install Catch2 and not how I use it. Sorry for possible misunderstanding.

Comment: If you provide a [mre] your question would be much easier to answer

Comment: @AlanBirtles I edited my question with recreated issue on much smaller scale. Hope it will be reproducible enough.

Comment: Does this help? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I appreciate the response, but not too much. I'm familiar with concepts of linking, I understand the basic reasons for linkage errors but here solution is unknown to me,

Comment: I don't know whether it's related, but this way of injecting conan toolchain and hardcoding CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is totally wrong. You should follow conan tutorials: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Fair point, if someone will want to inject toolchain file like this it needs to be either set() before project() or in command line args. Still not the source of the problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, change your `CMakeLists`:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(add LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.0.0)

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(add-test add-test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add-test PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
target_compile_features(add-test PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

And the way you call conan & cmake:

```
conan install . -of build-debug -s build_type=Debug -b missing 
cmake -S . -B build-debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build-debug/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build build-debug
```

Always try to set `CMake` toolchain file in command line arguments. Another way is to set variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` before `project()` call in `CMakeLists`. The last one is not a good practice anyway.

Comment: Well, that's it. Thanks for assistance! Can you elaborate how exactly I have failed in my example?

Comment: If using CMake>=3.23, it is also possible and convenient to use the generated CMake presets for a shorter command line, lik e``cmake --presets conan-release``

Comment: One of the failures is trying to set the toolchain in the CMakeLists.txt as ``set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "build/conan_toolchain.cmake")``. This is not possible, it has to be passed in the command line to be effective when the ``project()`` call happens.

Comment: @drodri Thanks, I edited answer with his information.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a configuration conflict.

The libs are compiled in **Release** configuration, but my working project is build using **Debug** configuration.
Some links are missing in CMake target of linked libs...

So beware of conflict between both.

EDIT: @Yunnosh, I'm taking note, and no I wasn't aware of this post, it's not like I had hours ahead of me to read every stack (no sarcasm).
So, I updated the post to be more like an "answer".

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: You can resolve this, if you [edit] and phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of commenting with a speculation and vage warning instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."